# Summing and grouping map values in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections, grouping, aggregation

I'm a newbie to Scala and I'm looking for a more succinct way to sum and group map values. Is there a better way than the following code:

```
def mapSum(thisMap: Map[Char, Int], thatMap: Map[Char, Int]) = {
  thisMap.transform { (k, v) => thatMap(k) + v }
}
```

Which would satisfy the following test:

```
@Test
def mapSum() {
  val map: Map[Char, Int] = Map('C' -> 1, 'D' -> 3)
  val newMap = mapSum(map, map)
  assertEquals(2, newMap('C'))
  assertEquals(6, newMap('D'))
}
```

Comment: Are you assuming that the maps always have the same keys?

Comment: If they don't (as in the coursera course you're taking), you should use `.withDefault`

Comment: @TravisBrown yep they always have the same keys.

Comment: @KimStebel I'm not taking a coursera course, I'm just playing around with Akka and writing a simple app, thanks though.

Comment: It's funny how that matches exactly one part of this week's assignment

Comment: Is the assignment a letter counting app? I'm modifying the Akka Scala tutorial example for letter counting just to get to know both Akka and Scala a little better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going for succinct, you're not going to get much better than your current version with the standard library (although note that you can drop the outer brackets to make it a two-liner).

[Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) provides some tools that can make this kind of thing a little more concise, including a monoid instance for `Map` and a pimped `unionWith` method:

```
scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> val m = Map('C' -> 1, 'D' -> 3)
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Int] = Map(C -> 1, D -> 3)

scala> m |+| m
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Int] = Map(C -> 2, D -> 6)

scala> (m unionWith m)(_ + _)
res1: Map[Char,Int] = Map(C -> 2, D -> 6)
```

Note that both of these approaches behave a little differently than yours, though—they don't choke at runtime if there are keys in the first that aren't in the second, and they don't silently ignore keys in the second that aren't in the first.

Comment: Looks good to me, thanks! I don't need it to handle missing keys for this case, but this solution is better in terms of defensive programming.

Comment: @Caps this uses an external library called scalaz... it's not worth introducing this dependency just to reduce your code by a few characters. Of course using a pre-written function is going to be succinct, but so is importing a function you've written yourself.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge: I hope it doesn't seem like I was trying to hide the fact that this involves an external library! (And there are of course many other reasons to use Scalaz.)

Comment: Don't worry, it doesn't; I just said that because Caps mentioned he's a newbie and might not realise that most projects don't use scalaz.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge yep I realise Scalaz is an external library, I just wanted to check if there was a more concise way of expressing the function and it looks like that there wasn't without using a function outside the standard Scala library so I accepted it as the answer. Cheers!